# R: window() function

Tags: r, window

I have a matrix named `x` that looks like this:

```
        pTime  Close
1  1275087600 1.2268
2  1275264000 1.2264
3  1275264300 1.2265
4  1275264600 1.2268
5  1275264900 1.2265
6  1275265200 1.2265
7  1275265500 1.2270
8  1275265800 1.2269
9  1275266100 1.2268
10 1275266400 1.2275
...1000 rows
```

I converted it to a time series datatype (`mts[2000]`) with `tser<- ts(x)1`

Now I want to use the `window()` function (from the `stats` package)  to isolate all rows between #5 and #8 based on their POSIX timestamp (the pTime field) but I get an error message.

```
> A<- as.POSIXct(tser[5,1],origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC")
> B<- as.POSIXct(tser[8,1],origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC")
> A
                    pTime 
"2010-05-31 01:15:00 EDT" 
> B
                    pTime 
"2010-05-31 01:30:00 EDT" 

> window(tser[,1],A,B)
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'end' value not changed
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you created the time-series object, the `ts` function was expecting the first argument to be data and for there to be no time. (You probably want to use zoo-objects anyway. They make more sense.) See what happens with this:

```
> window(tser[,1],start=5,end=8)
Time Series:
Start = 5 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 1275264900 1275265200 1275265500 1275265800
```

Your dates (in numeric representation) have become the data!

To use zoo it's pretty straight forward. I'm not sure what you starting point is. I had the data in a dataframe. If you actually have a matrix (which I doubt since it doesn't look like output from a matrix object) you could use the "[row,col]" style of access.

```
require(zoo)
zooser <- zoo(x=tser$Close, order.by=as.POSIXct(tser$pTime, origin="1970-01-01"))
window(zooser, start=A, end=B)
#2010-05-31 01:15:00 2010-05-31 01:20:00 2010-05-31 01:25:00 
#             1.2265              1.2265              1.2270 
#2010-05-31 01:30:00 
#             1.2269
```

Comment: I see - thanks...
With the zoo-objects is there a way to do what I'd like efficiently? I need to be able to access the time window based on start and end numerical POSIX timestamps.

Comment: Yes. `zoo-objects` have a `window` method. I will add an example.